# Can't reinstall macOS on iMac

Tags: macos, imac, disk-utility

I accidentally unmounted and erased the Macintosh HD in disk utility and restored to the OS X Base System, and now I can't reinstall macOS. The only disk that shows up in disk utility is the OS X Base System. Please Help!!!

Comment: It would be helpful to know what specific Mac you have. Also if you hold down Command-R it should get you into Internet Recovery Mode which will allow you to reinstall macOS, if your Mac is new enough.

Answer (score 1):

use Command+R For Internet Recovery To the version you were using and Command + Shift + R for internet recovery (to The latest version). When you will go to internet recovery a disk utility option will be there and u can configure , format your hdd there and install new os

Comment: This is assuming the iMac is "new enough".  Very old iMacs need to boot on installation media.